# Eclipse Project compatible with Java SE and Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have built a Java library for Java SE, and recently I've used it in an Android application. I would like to maintain compatibility in the library with both Java SE and Android.

What is the best practice when making a project in Eclipse for this situation? Top of my head, I see three solutions:

1) Create a Java project, and then switch the system library to JRE when I want to compile for Java SE, and to android.jar when it is for Android, but it is kind of a pain.

2) Create two Java projects, one for Java SE and another for Android, and share the same source folder.

3) Use Android as the least common denominator and create an Android project, and use it as a library in Java SE projects.

Is any of these viable? Are there better solutions?

Comment: To make the question more clear: the original project was in NetBeans, for Java SE. I copied the source code to an Eclipse Android project.

If the source code was shared, I would have compile-time checks for both Android and SE, instead of finding the problems at runtime by importing an external JAR.

I want to know if is there any "right way" of having this functionality, using only Eclipse. (it may be the case that importing the external JAR is the only solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a jar file created using Java SE you can use it directy in your Android project.  You just have to be careful not to use anything not supported on Android.  For example many of the javax.* libraries are not included.

In Eclipse you can do Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jar

Comment: Ok, that would be similar to using Java SE as the base project. However, this question is about avoiding "being careful", and have Eclipse doing those checks for me, both for Java SE and Android.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way you will find out is at runtime.  You will get a ClassNotFoundException.  Javax includes stuff like Corba, RMI, SWING, etc.  If you do need some Javax feature you can follow this guide: http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages.  I used it to add RMI stuff from the Harmony project.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct, since it seems to be the common practice.

Since it is the Java bytecode that is translated to Dalvik bytecode (and not the source code) even code specific from Java 6, 7, etc... can work, since the bytecode format is the same (as long as you don't use Classes or methods that do not exist in the Android API).

However, I've noticed subtle differences between recent Java APIs and older Android APIs (e.g., 2.2), such as the lack of some of the enumeration values in the TimeUnit class. In some cases, I'm using solution 2).